# AWS EKS + Fargate bug after multiple OOMKill restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, out-of-memory, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

TL;DR

I'm having trouble with an AWS EKS cluster running application pods on top of Fargate serverless nodes.

Here the steps to reproduce it:

- Create an EKS cluster
- Create a fargate profile for `default` namespace
- Run two pods in `default` namespace
- Make the second pod ping the first one, and leave it there
- In the first pod, use all available memory

  - It’s easier when you have python installed: `python3 -c "bytearray(512000000)"`
  - K8s will OOMKill it, and it should be restarted automatically
- Repeat steps above until you see the ping in the second pod stop working

Here's the pod manifest I'm using, but it can be any pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: root-shell
spec:
  containers:
  - command: ["sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - sleep infinity
    image: docker.io/library/alpine
    # Make two files and pick a different name for the second pod
    name: root-shell
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 64Mi
        cpu: 50m
```

Long description

My issue popped up this week when one of the pods lost network settings completely. After some debugging I figured that the pod was using more memory than it had been assigned to. This caused k8s to OOMKill it and restart the pod. After two or three restarts, the pod lost networking settings. nslookup or other requests to the outside didn't work, while all other pods in the cluster worked just fine. I noticed that pinging to the Fargate node also stopped working, so I'm assuming there might be something going on wrong with pod restart in the same fargate node. If I manually delete the pod, k8s will re-schedule a new pod on a new Fargate node where things work as they are supposed.

any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer (off the top of my head) for the restart issue (I will look into it and try to recreate the problem). However I wanted to point out that we read the "requests" to size the pod and not the "limits". See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-pod-configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! Yeah, I'll edit the question to use "requests" instead of "limits". But my use case (https://github.com/Linaro/qa-reports.linaro.org/blob/master/k8s/qareports-fetch-worker.yml) uses both and still restarts if the application uses too much memory. By trial and error I've managed to work around the restart by adding extra memory to "limits"

Comment: I've opened a ticket in AWS, will report back when I get an answer

Comment: Any update on this issue? I think I'm experiencing the same symptom.

Comment: @chaws did you figure it out?